# How to make the path long in routerProvider in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

My routerprovider is configured as follows:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {title : 'Home', templateUrl: 'partials/home.hbs' });
    $routeProvider.when('/sign-in', {title : 'Sign in', templateUrl: 'partials/sign-in.hbs'});
    $routeProvider.when('/sign-up', {title : 'Sign up', templateUrl: 'partials/sign-up.hbs'});
    $routeProvider.when('/404', {templateUrl: 'partials/404.hbs'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise('/404');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });

}]);
```

However, instead of using `'/sign-in'`, I want to use `'user/sign-in'` in the path parameter. I have been looking into something called wildcards but nothing I found has been helpful. Please direct me to how I can achieve this.

When I type `'user/sign-in'` instead of `'/sign-in'`, the browser goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: You should specify `/user/sign-in`. Not `user/sign-in`. And you'd better have a base url specified, or use absolute paths for your templates.

Comment: I didn't understand you. Can you clarify it more.

Comment: You're using requireBase: false. Do you understand what that means, and what the consequences are? If not, read the documentation of requireBase, and understand why you need either a base url specified, or absolute paths. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#relative-links

Comment: Thank you pointing that out. I was not using the <base> tag before because I set the require base to false, and it worked after adding it and setting it to true.